# Spring Rest: Obtain the host base URL before the first call

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I've developed a small REST API that runs inside a Spring container on a Tomcat server. As part of my boot sequence I need to be able to dump the base URL to a log file as:

```
String myUrl = ... 
LOGGER.info("My URL is {}", myUrl);
```

Which will display

```
My URL is http://myHostname:8080/myContext/url-pattern
```

This will happen BEFORE the first call to the API. Once the application has started I can check the logs and use `curl` or `wget` to check that the app is responding.

All the solutions I've seen depend on `HttpServletRequest`, but this requires a call to the REST interface

Ideally I'd like to grab the complete pattern from a Spring object injected into my class, however I don't mind constructing the information from different sources if no such object exists.

So far I've read:

- myHostname - `InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();`
- myContext - `servletContext.getContextPath()`

I've still got to get the port and the `url-pattern` (as defined in the web.xml) from somewhere.

**Note:** I understand that when I put my host is behind a load balancer then the domain of my REST API wont match myHostname and that's OK.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `WebApplicationInitializer` instead of `web.xml` then, you can get hold of context object in `onStartup` method.

```
public class WebMVCApplicationInitializer implements 
  WebApplicationInitializer {

    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) {
      XmlWebApplicationContext appContext = new XmlWebApplicationContext();
      ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration = 
        container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(appContext));
      registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
      registration.addMapping("*.request");
    }
}
```

you can then call the `getRealPath` method to get the absolute file path on the server's filesystem. Ref of `ServletContext` : [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath(java.lang.String))